# find directories having size greater than x MB

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Is it possible to find the directories only having size large than x MB.
Suppose, I want to find all the directories only whose size is large than 1000MB with only 1 maxdepth under /home, how to find it in ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question right, I think this might be what you want:

```
cd /home
du -sm * | awk '$1 > 1000'
```

This will show all directories in `/home` that contain more than 1000MB. If your version of `du` doesn't support `-m`, you can use `du -sk` and adjust the `awk` bit to look for more than 1,000,000KB instead...

Answer (score 6):

According to the [manpage](https://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/du/), the `-k` option is *POSIX* compliant but the `-m` option is not.

So the following is more portable (i.e. if you're on BSD, it will still work) but essentially does the same:

```
du -sk * | awk -v m=1000 '$1 > 1024*m'
```

Just set the awk variable *m* to the number of megabytes you would like as your cut-off.

I found this very useful for moving a batch of files, hence posting here for others' benefit.

To extend this to move all files meeting your criteria to another directory, you can adjust the `awk` command to print just the bit you need for the move (excluding the size) and then loop:

```
# moving all directories meeting the size criteria to another location:
for d in $(du -sk * | awk -v m=1000 '$1 > 1024*m {print $2}')
do 
    mv $d $DESTINATION
done
```

Comment: such posix, very comply :)