# Keep formatting when using for loop

Tags: bash

Let’s say I have data like this:

```
1.1G file1
2.2G file2
3.3G file3
```

When it’s doing:

```
1.1G
file1
2.2G
file2
3.3G
file3
```

What I want it to do:

```
1.1G file1
(Loops)
2.2G file2
(Loops)
3.3G file3
```

Here is my code:

```
cd /home/users
hdSize=$(du -h --max-depth=1 | awk '{print $1,$2}' | awk '$1~/G/' | sed '$d')
for sizeAlert in $hdSize
do
gbSize=$(echo $sizeAlert | awk ‘{print $1}’ | tr -d “G”)
#fileName=$(du -h —-max-depth=1 | awk ‘{print $2} | tr -d “./“)
echo $gbSize
done
```

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: You don't need two `awk` commands: `awk '$1 ~ /G/ { print $1, $2 }`

Comment: This _appears_ to be a duplicate of another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599214/3121039 .  Applying that answer yields 'du -sg /home/users/* | awk '$1 > 1'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find directories having size greater than x MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599109/find-directories-having-size-greater-than-x-mb)

Comment: Thank you. Below was the answer. I realized that I had the wrong slash when using my IFS. I had IFS=‘/n’ instead of IFS=‘\n’....Stupid mistake, thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason because your script is not working is that bash `for` loop splits when it finds any whitespace like space, tab, or newline.

So each item of your loop will be:

```sh
1.1G
file1
2.2G
file2
...
```

Hence, when you are executing `echo $sizeAlert | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d "G"` it makes sense for `1.1G` but it doesn't make any sense for `file1`.

you could set `IFS` (Internal Field Separator)

```sh
IFS=$'\n'
for sizeAlert in $hdSize
do
    fileName=$(echo $sizeAlert | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d "./")
    gbSize=$(echo $sizeAlert | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d "G")
    echo $gbSize $fileName
done
```

or you can use `read` in a `while` loop

```sh
while read gbSize fileName
do
    fileName=$(echo $fileName | tr -d "./")
    gbSize=$(echo $gbSize | tr -d "G")

    echo $gbSize $fileName
done <<< $hdSize
```

Anyway, a more efficient solution for your needs would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599109/find-directories-having-size-greater-than-x-mb?noredirect=1&lq=1) (already mentioned in comments)